# low query execution time SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have this query in sql server database

```
SELECT [Id]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[CreatedDate]
  ,[ModifiedBy]
  ,[ModifiedDate]
  ,[IsDeleted]
  ,[IsActive]
  ,[Type]
  ,[RelaseDate]
  ,[Prefix]
  ,[SubTitle]
  ,[Title]
  ,[Status]
  ,[Sequence]
  ,[Value]
  ,[Content]
  ,[Author]
  ,[Summery]
  ,[EndDate]
  ,[ViewedTime]
  ,[DefaultCategorieId]
  ,[URLTitle]
  ,[AlowComments]
  ,[HideImage]
  ,[ExternalLink]
FROM [SalesItem].[dbo].[Items]
where  Type='7a38bd0c-222f-4308-8dce-f7a2014d7d79' and IsDeleted <> 1
order by [CreatedDate] desc
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

the items has about 200,000 record the execution time for this query is about 00:80:30

Is there any way to faster the query. because the same table may have many different queries which they take longer execution time

Comment: Is this a transaction table or indexing is applied for this table?

Comment: there is no indexing applied for this table escape the Id column

Comment: You need to do the indexing on this table by identifying the correct column also try to write the query based on the id or column on which indexing is applied.

Comment: Try adding an NCI on type and IsDeleted

Comment: I hope you mean 8 minutes and 30 seconds and not 8 hours and 30 minutes...

Comment: yes 00:80:30 Sorry :D

Answer (score 1):

Considering `[Id]` as PK with identity enabled and NO index on `CreatedDate`, You can sort by `[ID]`

As ordering by both columns will be same. (Hope you are not updating `CreatedDate` later)

This query should be quicker

```
;with cte 
as
(
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [Id]) as rowid,
      ,[Id]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      ,[IsDeleted]
      ,[IsActive]
      ,[Type]
      ,[RelaseDate]
      ,[Prefix]
      ,[SubTitle]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Sequence]
      ,[Value]
      ,[Content]
      ,[Author]
      ,[Summery]
      ,[EndDate]
      ,[ViewedTime]
      ,[DefaultCategorieId]
      ,[URLTitle]
      ,[AlowComments]
      ,[HideImage]
      ,[ExternalLink]
    FROM [SalesItem].[dbo].[Items]
    where Type='7a38bd0c-222f-4308-8dce-f7a2014d7d79' and IsDeleted <> 1
)

select * from cte where rowid between 11 and 20
```

Please let me know the execution time this takes

Comment: there is no ordering by CreatedDate in your query

Comment: Read the top of my answer.. I ordered by `[id]` considering it's identity enabled column

Comment: yes, your query got much faster executing time less than 1 second

Comment: and is the result same for both of them ?

Comment: Careful with this.  Depending on how ID & CreatedDate are allocated you can end up out of sequence.  In multi-user environments transactions queue up and can get committed outside of the order that the IDs were allocated or the date set.  These are a pain if you're not expecting it and relying on that behaviour.  It will work almost all the time until it doesn't.  Very annoying!  If the ID & date are set outside of the database it might be ok.

Comment: Agree with every word @LoztInSpace